# Java Array Result = null

Tags: java, arrays, null

I have problem with my double arrays. After i run my File i got "null" values.

I do not know to parse this array above.

```
public class TestDesposit {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double [] rev = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0};
        double [] exp = {0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0};

        Result res = new Result (exp, rev);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(res.Resultat()));
    }
}

public class Result {
    double [] mExpenses;
    double [] mRevenue;
    double [] mResult;

    public Result (double[] pExpenses, double[] pRevenue) {
        mExpenses = pExpenses;
        mRevenue = pRevenue; 
    }

    public double [] Resultat () {
        for (int i = 0; i == 12; i++) {
            mResult[i] = mRevenue[i] - mExpenses[i];
        }
        return mResult;
    }   
}
```

Comment: dont run files... run code instead ; - )

Comment: Where do you ever initialize the mResult array? It's null  until you assign it a viable array.

Comment: And your loop condition is broken: `i == 12` should be `i < 12` or better, `i < mRevenue.length`

Comment: You also are using `i == 12` when it should be something like `i <= 12`

Comment: @JonSkeet Beat me to it :)

Comment: This isn't a NullPointerException problem - no exception is thrown by the given code, because it never gets into the body of the loop. There are two bugs here: non-initialization of `mResult`, and the loop condition.

Comment: Some parentheses are also missing at the end of the class `TestDesposit `?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels oh thank you. :)

Comment: And hint: your code is **super** confusing. Having a **field** mResult that some (badly named) method Resultat returns ... that is just plain **ugly**. Dont do that. If you provide access to a field, call the method "getSomething()"; but if you want the method to really compute something than have it create/return a local variable instead.

Comment: @GhostCat thank you for your tips ;), but i am a beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize your mResult array. Of course, this creates problems if your input arrays are not always going to have a length of 12, but that's a different problem.

You can try something like this:

```
double[] mResult = new double[12];
```

Then, as also people have been pointing out, you should change your for loop in `Resultat` to something like this:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < mRevenue.length ; i++){
```

Note, that you can also use `mResult.length` and `mExpenses.length` as they will also be the same in your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

At first, mResult is not init, so it is null object
Second, this code

```
for (int i=0 ; i ==12; i++){.. }
```

never run , i think u should change like that

```
public double [] Resultat (){
   mResult  = new double[12];
        for (int i=0 ; i <12; i++){
        mResult[i] = mRevenue[i] - mExpenses[i];
        }
    return mResult;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for (int i=0 ; i ==12; i++){
```

is wrong. You should try i<12